# Is it possible (and if so how) to make one proof for multiple private keys in ECDSA

Tags: elliptic-curves, signature, dsa

Lets say I have a message that needs to be signed by two keys that were generated using ECDSA

Is it possible to make a signature that accounts for both keys, meaning I can verify with both and see they are valid?

An example, if we need a cryptocurrency example:

Address 1 has 10 coins
Address 2 has 10 coins

Both inputs are in the transaction, and now need to be signed. Is it possible to make it so only one signature is made, but accounts for both addresses?

Comment: You simply asking one public key works at least two private keys, not possible with ECDSA. If you follow the correctness you can see the reason.

Comment: Are you actually looking for the [Multi-Signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multisignature)